# Are annotations inherited from interfaces or super-class?

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following interface:

```
interface Somethingable {

    @Foo
    void doSomething();
}
```

Now if I implement this interface, will the `@Foo` annotation be inherited on my implementation of `doSomething()` or do I have to write it again?

If it's inherited, is it a bad practice?

Comment: It depends on the annotation, they have a retain property.

Comment: @daniu the [`RetrainPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) defines when the annotation is erased, not whether it is inherited.